# IE9 and Two dimensional arrays errors

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, google-maps

theI'm not experiencing any issues in firefox, chrome, IE11, IE10, but IE9 gives me this:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'getPosition' of undefined or null reference 
line 391 character 3

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '2' of undefined or null reference 
line 332 character 4

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '2' of undefined or null reference 
line 332 character 4

Looking at my code, this last error ( the earliest one ) comes from this line:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[y][2], locations[y][1])
```

Let's put it into context:

```
var locations = []; 

 ...
 ...

jQuery('.store').each( function() {
   var theLatitude = jQuery(this).find('.latitude').text();
   var theLongitude = jQuery(this).find('.longitude').text();
   var theName = jQuery(this).find('.location-title').text();

   locations.push([theName, theLatitude, theLongitude, theDistance]);
});


 ...
 ...



  var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
       setTimeout(function(y){
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[y][2], locations[y][1]),
          map: carte,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          icon: iconlocation
        })

        gmarkers.push(marker); //Store the marker object for later    

       },300 * i, i);// end setTimeout
    }// end for
```

This prevents markers from showing on the map. The map itself loads correctly.
What's odd is that if I replace

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[y][2], locations[y][1])
```

with

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.481819, -73.625822)
```

The markers still don't show.

Also, getPosition() on my gmarkers array gives me the undefined error:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'getPosition' of undefined or null reference 
line 391 character 3

What the hell IE ?

Comment: done a `console.log(locations)` to see what's really in there? Plus, where's this `y` coming from inside your `setTimeout` call? There's no `y` defined anywhere in your code, you just suddenly start using it.

Comment: What does your array look like?  Any "hanging commas" (after the last element of the array), early versions of IE add an extra null element to the array when you do that that wreaks havoc with code that works in all other browsers.  Though from you code, looks like you just have bad data somewhere in your array or are iteration past the end.

Comment: @Marc B
JEEZ! Of course. I have no idea why there was a Y there. Thanks you eagle eyed savior.

Comment: As for the getPosition() error, I'm still getting it because its related to another array. I'm pushing each marker into my gmarkers array.
gmarkers.push(marker)

I then call findUser(gmarkers, carte);

this retrieves the user's position and calls the function that computes the distance:

userPos = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);

computeDistance(userPos, gmarkers, carte);


then this is where the error occurs:
var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween( origin,destination[compteur].getPosition() ) / 1000;